# Python Pandas delete multiple rows based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete some rows based on column values. I am using pandas.

I have four key words for which I want to check a particular column.

`df_1[df_1['Item'] != 'YoY Growth']` I know this will delete a column that has 'YoY Growth' however I have not found an efficient way to combine all my key words into one line so I can delete all the rows containing any of the key words ?

I also tried using the method below but I am having some trouble with syntax

```
indexNames = df_1[ df_1['Customer'] == 'YoY Growth'].index

indexNames = df_1[ df_1['Customer'] == 'WoW Growth'].index

df_1.drop(indexNames)
```

Comment: `df_1[~df_1['Customer'].isin(['YoY Growth', 'WoW Growth'])]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do :

```py
indexNames = df_1[df_1['Customer'].isin(['YoY Growth', 'WoW Growth'])].index
df_1.drop(indexNames)
```